# Swift LayoutConstraint breaks on keyboard frame change

Tags: swift, nslayoutconstraint

I have a simple ViewController with a `UITextView` inside of a `UIStackView`. I've also stored an `NSLayoutConstraint` which is the bottom anchor of the stackView.

When the textView becomes first responder or resigns from first responder, two `Notification`s get triggered. The `keyboardDidShowNotification` works great. The issue is with `keyboardWillHideNotification`.

I’ve noticed that when I change the keyboard's frame by clicking the emojis button and then dismiss the keyboard, something breaks with the constraints.

As you can see in the gif below, as long as I don't go to the emojis section, the keyboard dismisses properly and the constraints are updated also properly. When I do go to the emojis section, then the `bottomStackViewBottomConstraint` and `schoolTextViewTopConstraint`  go below that they should.

Here's what happens;

[image]

And here is the code;

```
fileprivate var schoolTextViewTopConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!
fileprivate var bottomStackViewBottomConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!

fileprivate func setupNotifications() {
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.keyboardDidShow), name: UIResponder.keyboardDidShowNotification, object: nil)
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.keyboardWillHide), name: UIResponder.keyboardWillHideNotification, object: nil)
}

@objc fileprivate func keyboardDidShow(notification: Notification) {
    if let infoKey = notification.userInfo?[UIResponder.keyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey], let rawFrame = (infoKey as AnyObject).cgRectValue {
        let keyboardFrame = self.view.convert(rawFrame, from: nil)
            
        bottomStackViewBottomConstraint.constant = -(keyboardFrame.height) + self.view.safeAreaInsets.bottom
        schoolTextViewTopConstraint.constant = -keyboardFrame.height + 180
    }
        
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0, animations: {
        self.sendCommentButton.isHidden = false
        self.toggleMuteButton.isHidden = true
        self.shareButton.isHidden = true
        self.leaveRoomButton.isHidden = true
            
        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
    }, completion: nil)
}
    
@objc fileprivate func keyboardWillHide(notification: Notification) {
    schoolTextViewTopConstraint.constant = 0
    bottomStackViewBottomConstraint.constant = 0
        
    sendCommentButton.isHidden = true
        
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, animations: {
        self.toggleMuteButton.isHidden = self.currentUserRole == VoiceRoomRole.listener
        self.shareButton.isHidden = false
        self.leaveRoomButton.isHidden = false
            
        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
    }, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: *"... something breaks with the constraints ..."* -- you need to tell us **what** breaks.

Comment: I updated my question. Please take a look again.